# Unable to save data once logged in to app

Tags: android, android-intent

I made an app where initial step is to login for user. In `Nav_Drawer` activity (main activity) I have set Profile Picture and User Name. From floating button I used to open camera for scanning QR code(QR Code scanner is integrated of zing from GitHub)  and as the code is scanned activity return back to `Nav_Drawer` activity(main Activity) but the user Profile Pic and User Name has set to default I.e. Null..

Now I want to keep these data without loading them back from internet.

Help me! Thank you for Help..

Comment: For image you have to store it in catch memory

Answer (score 0):

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), 0);
    pin = sharedPreferences.getString("pin", ""); //use to call api


    accType = sharedPreferences.getString("accType", "unpaid");
```

save your data in shared preferences , and use that to set your views,and set your variable data fields in onResume method